# PHP Returns No Rows When a Field is Empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop that iterates through the rows returned from a DB query.

**Query**

```
$sql = "SELECT t.barcode AS barcode, t.code, t.brand, t.name, t.cost, t.price, t.vat, SUM(n.stock) AS stock
    FROM t 
    INNER JOIN c.am ON t.code=am.code
    INNER JOIN n ON t.code=n.code WHERE (n.name='X' OR n.name='Y') 
    AND t.code IN ($in)
    GROUP BY t.code, t.name, t.cost, t.salesprice, t.vat";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

  echo "<table id='maintable'><tr><th>Barcode</th><th>Name</th><th>Brand</th></tr>";
  while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
   if(empty($row['barcode'])){
   $barcode = "none";
   }
   $barcode = $row['barcode'];
   $name = $row['name'];
   $brand = $row['brand'];

   echo "<td>" . $barcode . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $brand . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

The problem is if barcode is empty (not in the DB table), no rows get displayed.  However if there is a barcode, the row DOES display. In my example I have tried to check if $row['barcode'] is empty to assign a string so that the row will still display but its unsuccessful.

In the Table itself in the database, the Barcode has a Null field set to YES and Default Field set to NULL so I have also tried:

```
   if(is_null($row['barcode'])) { ..... };
```

But unsuccessful.

Somewhere I read that empty can equate to: '', 0 and NULL so I'm thinking it's failing because checking if "empty" is the wrong approach?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: what is the actual query you're executing?

Comment: show us full fragment of code with mysql query string please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(empty($row['barcode'])){
   $barcode = "none";
} else {
   $barcode = $row['barcode'];
}
```

or even better:

```
$barcode = empty($row['barcode'])?"none":$row['barcode'];
```

So your code would be:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
   $barcode = empty($row['barcode'])?"none":$row['barcode'];
   $name = $row['name'];
   $brand = $row['brand'];

   echo "<td>" . $barcode . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $brand . "</td>";
}
```

**UPDATE** Not sure about your database structure, but if you need some empty `t.barcode` values your query could be like:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
      t.barcode AS barcode, 
      n.code,  
      t.brand, t.name, t.cost, t.price, t.vat, 
      SUM(n.stock) AS stock
FROM n 
LEFT JOIN t 
ON t.code=n.code 
   AND t.code IN ($in)
WHERE (n.name='X' OR n.name='Y') 
GROUP BY n.code, t.name, t.cost, t.salesprice, t.vat";
```

And I don't understand what is `INNER JOIN c.am ON t.code=am.code` stands for, maybe you should delete it.

Comment: Alex this makes sense to me and I've tried your example but "none" is not getting assigned to the barcode field and still no rows display when there is no barcode stored in the dB.

Comment: The full query is added.  So my while loop etc is just an example

Comment: BINGO Alex.  INNER JOIN c.am ON t.code=am.code was not required (it was getting used in another script). It works now so thank you ever so much for your help.  Much appreciated. Hexana

Answer (score 3):

Your conditional logic is being followed by this line:

```
$barcode = $row['barcode'];
```

Whatever was assigned to `$barcode` previously is being *overwritten*.

Looks like you wanted that to be `else`, or you wanted that line *before* the conditional test.

---

As an alternative, you could just modify your query to return the string "none" in place of NULL with an IFNULL function, assuming that barcode is character type.

```
SELECT IFNULL(t.barcode,'none') AS barcode
     , ...
  FROM t
```

---

**EDIT**

The question has been edited (after I posted my answer), to add a SQL query to the question.

I thought the problem was that an empty (zero length) string was being assigned to a variable, and the intent was to replace the empty string with a literal.

Comment: I think he/she should manage that logic in the PHP side. Don't you agree?

Comment: @EmilioGort there is mostly no difference where to handle that

Comment: @Alex for compatibility with other system or if you use that query/SP in other places and you don't want to see the 'None'...is more that logic or presentation shouldn't be in the DB...an idea, but you always can do what you want...it's a thought

Comment: @EmilioGort there is nothing wrong with compatability if you set psrticular mysql query in particular php file, or object or library. this query belongs to the current code fragment and breaks nothing in others.

Comment: I agree with you just to make the habit that presentation shouldn't be manage in the db. +1 for you for the ternary option in your answer

Comment: the data type is varchar(48) in the database